# Add Event Handler to MenuItem added dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem

I have a `MenuItem`. I have to add sub `MenuItem`s to this `MenuItem`. But the number of sub `MenuItem`s is returned through a function. So, I added the following function which I am calling in the constructor:

```
void AddMenuItems()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= ItemCount(); i++)
    {
        mnuItem.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Name = "MenuItem" + i, Header = "Menu Item " + i });
    }
}

int ItemCount()
{
    return 3;
}
```

I hard coded the `ItemCount()` return value for now. What I want now is, how do I add a click event to these menu items.

Am I doing this the right way? Any suggestions as to improve this method are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following, change the menu item creation too

```
for (int i = 1; i <= ItemCount(); i++)
{
    var menuItem = new MenuItem() { Name = "MenuItem" + i, Header = "Menu Item " + i };
    menuItem.Click += item_Click;
    mnuItem.Items.Add(menuItem);    
}
```

And then the click handler will be defined as

```
void item_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:
The name 'var' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Abhishek, please see the edit I made to my post, does your loop look like that?

Comment: I have one more doubt. Based on this item click, i have to add tabs to a tab control. how should i do that?

Comment: You'll need to ask another question for that. But off the top of my head I would add the tab creation code into the click handler. You're probably going to need to use the name of the menu item to distinguish which menu item was clicked